# How to get the value of Text box that is triggered by the radio button using jquery in the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my test case the user is given two options i.e ielts or toefl.  If the user selects ielts then an input box opens and he enters his ielts score.  What I'm looking for is to capture that value that is entered in the input box.  Below is my code:

```
<div id='show-me' style='display:none' class="ds">
    <label for="number" id="uel">IELTS:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:6.5" id="ranju" name="toefl" reuqired/>
</div>
<div id='touch-me' style='display:none'>
    <label for="number" id="uel">TOFEL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fle" placeholder="Example:90" id="ranju" required/>
</div>
<script>
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    if (($('input[name=cgpa]').val() != '') && $('input[name=gre]').val() != '')) {

    jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#myModel").modal('show');
    console.log($("input[name=test]:checked").val());
    } else {
        alert("Enter details");
    }

});

</script>
```

Here is how it should work:

- step 1: User clicks on one of the radio buttons
- step 2: A text box
  related to the radio button opens
- step 3: The user enters a value
- step 4: console.log(-----) should print the captured value

Comment: There is no use case where you would ever need to call `jQuery.noConflict();` in the middle your code

Comment: @charliefti  there is one..i just trimmed it and uploaded the needed code.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  If you want the value of the text box please update your question otherwise you are already getting the value of the radio button where you log it in the console.

Comment: I'm looking for the value of the text box

Comment: Still not clear what event triggers getting the value or what problems you are having since you already are using getter for value on other elements. Overall this question doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your html code:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="ielts"/> IELTS &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="type" value="tofel"/> TOFEL
<div id='show-ielts' style='display:none'>
    <label for ="number" id="uel">IELTS:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:6.5"  name="ielts" reuqired/>
</div>
<div id ='show-tofel' style='display:none'>
    <label for ="number" id="uel">TOFEL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tofel"  placeholder="Example:90" required/>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

And then the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // listen the radio button changed event and display the target field.
        $('input[name="type"]').change(function() {
            $('#show-ielts, #show-tofel').hide();
            $('#show-' + $(this).val()).show();
        });

        // when submit
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
            var target_field = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

            // console your target field value
            console.log(target_field + ' value is: ' + $('input[name="' + target_field + '"]').val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: 1. locate the input field by the radio button value which user selected. 2. use the jquery filter to find the input field.(based on the radio button value. `#show-ielts` and `#show-tofel`), then show it. 3. when submit, we should use the `input[type="radio"]:checked` to filter the radio button which one is checked. 4. also use the radio button's value to find the input field and get the value from it.

Comment: 1. to ensure that your input field name is `ielts` and `tofel`, cause this is searched by input field name. 2. in some version of jquery and broswer, we can't get the value from radio button through the filter expression. so change the `$('input[type="radio"]:checked')` to `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')` to get selected radio button.